# I can't communicate between 2 dockers that connected to the same network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 2 dockers, one is the client and the other is the server.

After deployment, I can't reach the server from the client.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  # should be locate once in the control node
  log_server:
    build: ./logServer/
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "4000:80"
    networks:
      - logging-net
    volumes:
      - persistLogs:/var/log/files
      - sharedError:/var/errors

  # We should have 1 on EVERY node and configure it to 
  # collect logs from all containers in the node
  client:
    depends_on:
      - log_server
    build: ./logClient/
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - LOG_SERVER=log_server
    networks:
      - logging-net
    volumes:
      - nodeWideLogs:/var/log/files
      - sharedError:/var/errors
    deploy:
      mode: global
               
  

networks:
  logging-net:
    external: true
  
volumes:
  sharedError:
    driver: local
  persistLogs:
    driver: local
  nodeWideLogs:
    driver: local
```

here is how I try to communicate from the client:

```
python
import reuests
token = requests.get('http://log_server:4000/login', auth=('clientLog', 'Bbn4uazkVvfyHxhcbrhk2MeAE9yPh4r4nRfHWv'))
```

This is the error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='log_server', port=4000): Max retries exceeded with url: /login (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f0c2f470220>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

What I do rung?
They are both on the same network...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if your log server is listening port 80, but you're trying to connect on port 4000.

Remember that port mappings don't affect container-to-container communication; they only affect on which *host* ports a service is exposed. Since you're connecting directly to the `log_server` container you should just be using port 80.